# Android asyncTask array returning null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

Im trying to rewrite some code because android specifies that you must place network tasks  on a separate thread in version 4.0, I had a block of code that was working perfectly but since I tried placing it into the async task I now cant get it to work at all, Ive set up my async task to return an array but it continuously returns null, is there anything obvious here that Im not seeing?

```
package com.imagetest.second;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImagetestActivity extends Activity {
// Elements media;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String url = "http://www.goal.com/en-ca/news/4196/brazil/2012/05/23/3123112/ganso-set-for-knee-surgery";

    new getMainImg().execute(url);

}

private class getMainImg extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;

        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        List<Element> media = new ArrayList<Element>();
        media = result.select("img[src]");

        List<Dog> theImportantUrlArray = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        for (Element src : media) {
            String srcStr = src.attr("src");
            String first7st = srcStr.substring(0, 7);
            if (first7st.equals("http://")) {

                Integer theHeight = getBitmapFromURL(srcStr).getHeight();
                theImportantUrlArray.add(new Dog(srcStr, theHeight));

            }

        }
        Collections.sort(theImportantUrlArray, new Dog());

        Integer thetweetpic = theImportantUrlArray.get(0).getDogAge();
        String theTweetUrl = theImportantUrlArray.get(0).getDogName();

        Toast.makeText(ImagetestActivity.this,
                thetweetpic.toString() + " " + theTweetUrl,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public class Dog implements Comparator<Dog>, Comparable<Dog> {
    private String theUrl;
    private int height;

    Dog() {
    }

    Dog(String n, int a) {
        theUrl = n;
        height = a;
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return theUrl;
    }

    public int getDogAge() {
        return height;
    }

    // Overriding the compareTo method
    public int compareTo(Dog d) {
        return (this.theUrl).compareTo(d.theUrl);
    }

    // Overriding the compare method to sort the age
    public int compare(Dog d, Dog d1) {
        return d1.height - d.height;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is `result` null, or is `media` full after you call select? Which array is null and when?

Comment: Im getting a string out of bounds exception 05-24 00:19:24.959: E/AndroidRuntime(608): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=7

Comment: On what line? I would like to help you but I can't step through your code so I am going to need more information.

Comment: how do I find the line? Ive tried learning android debugging a few times but couldnt understand it

Comment: Well its not android debugging, its Java debugging (which is essentially the same as most C style languages). I don't need to know the line number, I need to know what method you called that caused the crash. You can figure this out by setting a breakpoint  in the method and stepping one line at a time. On that note, it sounds like you need to learn more about general debugging skills. You won't have much luck getting answers on StackOverflow unless you can narrow the problem down a lot.